# Can I use a single Hardware Ledger for multiple coins

Tags: hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

I am about to buy a hardware ledger to store my coins but I was wondering if I would be needing one ledger per coin I own or if one can hold all or some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a single Ledger for multiple coins.

[Here is the list of supported coins.](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005304449-Which-altcoins-and-tokens-are-supported-by-the-Ledger-products-)

Comment: Follow up. I see X coin coming soon. Is this a firmware upgrade that just adds support to another coin?

Comment: Never mind, saw it at the end of the site :)

Comment: Firmware update :)